# EER diagram forward engineering error: mysql ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, key, constraints

I am using the MySQL workbench to create a database structure using the EER diagram. When it was complete I used the forward engineering function to create a sql file of my model:[EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ8LD.png)

When I try to deploy this query on MySQL server it keeps giving me mysql ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Can somebody help me?

```
    -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TblPersoon`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`TblPersoon` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblPersoon` (
  `PersoonID` INT NOT NULL,
  `GSM` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Functie` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Voornaam` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Achternaam` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersoonID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TblDevice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`TblDevice` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblDevice` (
  `DeviceID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Van` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Tot` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DeviceID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TblEvents`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`TblEvents` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblEvents` (
  `EventID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Naam` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Locatie` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ContactpersoonID` INT NOT NULL,
  `VerantwoordelijkeID` INT NOT NULL,
  `EventNaam` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EventID`),
  INDEX `PersoonID_idx` (`ContactpersoonID` ASC),
  INDEX `PersoonID_idx1` (`VerantwoordelijkeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `PersoonID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContactpersoonID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblPersoon` (`PersoonID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `PersoonID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VerantwoordelijkeID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblPersoon` (`PersoonID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TblContainer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`TblContainer` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblContainer` (
  `ContainerID` INT NULL,
  `Plaats` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ContainerID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TblInstallatie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`TblInstallatie` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblInstallatie` (
  `InstallatieID` INT NULL,
  `ContainerID` INT NULL,
  `DeviceID` INT NULL,
  `Van` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Tot` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `EventID` INT NULL,
  `Omschrijving` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `VerantwoordelijkeID` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`InstallatieID`),
  INDEX `PersoonID_idx` (`VerantwoordelijkeID` ASC),
  INDEX `DeviceID_idx` (`DeviceID` ASC),
  INDEX `EventID_idx` (`EventID` ASC),
  INDEX `ContainerID_idx` (`ContainerID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `PersoonID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VerantwoordelijkeID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblPersoon` (`PersoonID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `DeviceID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DeviceID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblDevice` (`DeviceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `EventID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EventID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblEvents` (`EventID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `ContainerID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContainerID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblContainer` (`ContainerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TblLog`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`TblLog` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblLog` (
  `LogID` INT NOT NULL,
  `InstallatieID` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LogID`),
  INDEX `InstallatieID_idx` (`InstallatieID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `InstallatieID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`InstallatieID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TblInstallatie` (`InstallatieID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Post is updated

Comment: You are referencing the table `TblPersoon`. Does it exist?

Comment: I will upload the whole sql, TblPersoon is created as first table

Answer (score 0):

I noticed both foreign key constraints in `TblEvents` have the same name, `PersoonID`. Constraint names must be unique, and in fact they **must be unique within the whole schema**, not only within the table in which they are defined.

Also `TblInstallatie` has its own constraint named `PersoonID`. So if you just change one of the constraint names in `TblEvents`, it still results in an error when you get to `CREATE TABLE TblInstallatie`.

I tested this with MySQL 5.6 and I got it to work by giving distinct names to both constraints in `TblEvents`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TblEvents` (
  ...
  CONSTRAINT `PersoonID1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContactpersoonID`)
    ...
  CONSTRAINT `PersoonID2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VerantwoordelijkeID`)
    ...
```

The later creation of `TblInstallatie`'s `CONSTRAINT PersoonID` can then succeed.